# c++ How to flatten a view from xtensor, without deep copying?

Tags: c++, 3d, xtensor

Is it possible to directly flatten a view from xtensor? 
Something like:

```cpp
xt::xarray<double> arr3d = xt::linspace<double>(1.0, 21970.0, 21970);
arr3d.reshape({13, 13, 130});
xt::xtensor<double, 3> data = arr3d;

xt::xtensor<double, 3>  data_view = xt::view(data, xt::range(9, 12),xt::range(9, 12),xt::range(9, 12));
xt::xtensor<double, 1>  flat_data = xt::flatten(data_view);
```

If I try to flatten the view directly, results differ.

```cpp
xt::xtensor<double, 1>  flat_data = xt::flatten(xt::view(data, xt::range(9, 12),xt::range(9, 12),xt::range(9, 12)));
```

I was thinking about flattening directly, for a more clean and optimized code. Is there a way of doing it? Or should I copy the view to an auxiliary variable before flattening it?

Obs.: 
flattening directly outputs (wrong answer):
16390, 16391, 16392, 16393, 16394, 16395, 16396, 16397, 16398, 16399, 16400, 16401, 16402, 16403, 16404, 16405, 16406, 16407, 16408, 16409, 16410, 16411, 16412, 16413, 16414, 16415, 16416.

copying before flattening outputs what I need (a kernel window):
16390, 16391, 16392, 16520, 16521, 16522, 16650, 16651, 16652, 18080, 18081, 18082, 18210, 18211, 18212, 18340, 18341, 18342, 19770, 19771, 19772, 19900, 19901, 19902, 20030, 20031, 20032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug, could you open an issue on [xtensor's repo](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor) please?

Also you can initialize your first tensor in a single line and avoid a copy:

```
xt::xtensor<double, 3> = xt::linspace<double>(1.0, 21970.0, 21970).reshape({13, 13, 130});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I opened issue [1454]{https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor/issues/1454}.

Trying to initialize the first tensor directly gives me an error, though:


    `error: no member named 'reshape' in 'xt::xfunction<xt::detail::cast<double>::functor,
      xt::xgenerator<xt::detail::arange_generator<double, double>, double, std::array<unsigned long, 1> > >'
 xt::xtensor<double, 3> data = xt::linspace<double>(1.0, 100.0, 100).reshape({2, 5, 10});`

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is available in master only, not in 0.19 branch, sorry for that. It will be available in next release.

Comment: Ok. Great! Thanks a lot.